# How can I concentrate ions in a very small area?

Tags: experimental-physics, physical-chemistry, plasma-physics, electrochemistry, ions

I am interested in concentrating ions in a very small area, so the ion density of that region is elevated above normal levels.

What is the field of study, or term, that describes what I am talking about, and how have these been achieved?

(Edit: for clarity, I am not referring to nuclear fusion. I am looking for a field that merely tries to increase ion density in a given area, which is probably a part of nuclear fusion but I am sure that there is a specific term to refer to doing such things.)

Comment: What densities are you trying to achieve? Are you talking about inertial fusion? That's not ions that are being compressed but a plasma. Charged ion beams can be focused with accelerators, but there are many orders of magnitude in difference between plasma and ion beam densities.

Comment: What do you mean by normal levels??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electric arcs have high-density plasmas, which might be what you are looking for. If you make an electric arc in a low-pressure environment, you get a [capacitively coupled plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitively_coupled_plasma) or [glow discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_discharge). You can also make [inductively coupled plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductively_coupled_plasma) by passing alternating magnetic fields from a magnetic coil connected to a microwave transformer. The last one is quite popular for  plasma cleaning tech. The order of plasma densities would be like :
Electric Arc>>CCP>ICP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to embedding ions in a material, then you probably want to search up "doping" in the field of materials science. Perhaps search for "spatially anisotropic doping" for results related to uneven spatial distributions of the ions. You may want to add clarity about the applications of your question and the materials involved.